# Split text by space on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2012, substring

I'm using SQL Server 2012, so no string split function available.

Consider that I have a table called `DISK_VOLUME` with only one column `RESULT` and currently 4 rows:

```
RESULT
----------------------------------------
P: 220825387008  959589646336  DADOS       
I: 166207356928  959589646336  INDEXS       
E: 636080054272  799165902848  LOG          
C: 462246113280  999651536896
```

What I want is a query that splits those rows by space, showing 4 columns like:

```
Caption  | Space 1      | Space 2        | Volume Name 
---------+--------------+----------------+--------------
P:       | 220825387008 | 959589646336   | DADOS 
I:       | 166207356928 | 959589646336   | INDEXS 
E:       | 636080054272 | 799165902848   | LOG 
C:       | 462246113280 | 999651536896   |
```

But there's no control of the amount of spaces in the string. It can have like

- Word space Word
- Word space space space space Word

Which means that using `charindex(' ', ini_pos, ini_pos + 1)` by itself won't work since I can't rely on having the next word right after the spaces lookup.

So basically what I was looking for is any function or combination of commands that splits a row by spaces dynamically (recursive function, xml, IDK). All my attempts on doing so have failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string using `XML`. You first need to convert the string to `XML` and replace the space with `start` and `end` `XML` `tags`.

Once the string is converted into `XML`, you can use `XQuery` to get the result in proper format.

To show the data in multiple column you can simply use `PIVOT`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT 
 F1.results,
 O.splitdata,
 row_number() over(partition by results order by (select 1)) rn FROM
    (
        SELECT *, 
        cast('<X>'+replace(F.results,' ','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter 
        from [YourTableName] F
        )F1
        CROSS APPLY
        ( 
            SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(500)') as splitdata 
            FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D) 
        ) O
        where splitdata <> ''
    ) 

 select [1] [Caption],[2] [Space1],[3] [Space2], [4] [Volume Name] 
 from CTE c
 PIVOT (max(splitdata) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) pvt
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/MIXSQT73573)

**Output**

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| Caption | Space1       | Space2       | Volume Name |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| C:      | 462246113280 | 999651536896 | NULL        |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| E:      | 636080054272 | 799165902848 | LOG         |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| I:      | 166207356928 | 959589646336 | INDEXS      |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| P:      | 220825387008 | 959589646336 | DADOS       |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a `fn_split` function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_split 
( @Words nvarchar(MAX)
, @splitStr varchar(50) 
)
RETURNS @Result_Table TABLE
       (
         [word] nvarchar(max) NULL
       )
BEGIN 
    Declare @TempStr nvarchar(MAX)

    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@splitStr,@Words)>0)
    BEGIN
        Set @TempStr=SUBSTRING(@Words,1,CHARINDEX(@splitStr,@Words)-1)
        Insert into @Result_Table (word) Values (@TempStr)

        Set @Words = REPLACE(@Words,@TempStr+@splitStr,'')
    END/*End While*/

    IF(LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@Words)))>0 And CHARINDEX(@splitStr,RTRIM(LTRIM(@Words)))=0) 
    Begin
        Set @TempStr=@Words 

        Insert into @Result_Table (word) Values (@TempStr)

    End 

   RETURN 
END
```

then use a little skill let multiple to one space on `DISK_VOLUME`, replace three times.

Next step use `row_number` window function get the number for condition aggregate function.

```
;WITH CTE as(
    SELECT val,word,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY val order by val) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT replace(replace(replace(DISK_VOLUME,' ','*&'),'&*',''),'*&',' ') val
        FROM T
    ) t1 CROSS APPLY fn_split(t1.val,' ') v
)

SELECT max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN word END) 'Caption',
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN word END) 'Space1',
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN word END) 'Space 2',
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN word END) 'Volume Name '
FROM CTE
GROUP BY val
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10a45864572f56c5775ad21f08e8cd01)

Comment: Although I prefer the XML solution above, this also works, thank you!